# How to loop on a JSON data and put part of it in another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, loops

I want to loop on a JSON data and put a part of it in a sperate array.

I have this JSON data:

```
{"msg":"[{"parent":"0","child":"1"},{"parent":"0","child":"2"}]","sig":"3045022100b3f03c83ed1f3d0bc72475550f23c0dd38277b0e2230e1fe76611577b2ca4b7e022037c77d37cc08ed897d0d1a11d09342e6abb73e641d20d5d55f367044d5489ddf"}
```

I want to make an array of `msg` only like this:

```
[ '0', '1', '0', '2 ]
```

My code:

```js
var message = '[{"msg":[{"parent":"0","child":"1"},{"parent":"0","child":"2"}],"sig":"3045022100b3f03c83ed1f3d0bc72475550f23c0dd38277b0e2230e1fe76611577b2ca4b7e022037c77d37cc08ed897d0d1a11d09342e6abb73e641d20d5d55f367044d5489ddf"}]'
var g = [];
const jsArray = JSON.parse(message);
Array.from(jsArray.msg).forEach(jsdata => {
  console.log(jsdata)
  g.push(jsdata.parent, jsdata.child)
})
console.log(g);
```

I could not meet what I really want it says:

```
[
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined,
  ... 10 more items
]
```

How could I solve this, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `msg` contain String value? If so, you need to `JSON.parse` that as well: `Array.from(JSON.parse(jsArray.msg))`

Comment: The JSON string is not valid JSON. The array contained in `msg` cannot be quoted to be legit.

Comment: As you can see, your code produces a syntax error because the JSON is malformed. Please edit your question to provide the _actual_ JSON string.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks! you're right. I have edited the code.

Comment: Great - please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as simple as using the `.map` method to gather the data and then flatting the final array to get you output.

```js
var message ='[{"msg":[{"parent":"0","child":"1"},{"parent":"0","child":"2"}],"sig":"3045022100b3f03c83ed1f3d0bc72475550f23c0dd38277b0e2230e1fe76611577b2ca4b7e022037c77d37cc08ed897d0d1a11d09342e6abb73e641d20d5d55f367044d5489ddf"}]';

let data = JSON.parse(message);
let output = data[0].msg.map(d=>[d.parent,d.child]).flat();
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below to loop the inner array:

```js
    var message ='[{"msg":[{"parent":"0","child":"1"},{"parent":"0","child":"2"}],"sig":"3045022100b3f03c83ed1f3d0bc72475550f23c0dd38277b0e2230e1fe76611577b2ca4b7e022037c77d37cc08ed897d0d1a11d09342e6abb73e641d20d5d55f367044d5489ddf"}]';
    let g=[];
    const jsArray = JSON.parse(message);
    jsArray.forEach(jsMsgData => {
         // console.log(jsMsgData.msg);
         jsMsgData.msg.forEach(jsdata => {
            g.push(jsdata.parent, jsdata.child);
         })
    });
    console.log(g);
```

check full code here: https://ideone.com/QywYfb

Comment: I assume he is getting data from an api call so json format should be correct or else he won't get lots of undefined values pushed in `g` right

Comment: Thanks for answering! The link of full code is not working. Could you please check the link?

Comment: Its working for me I checked in incognito mode so no access issues. Maybe your firewall is blocking it.

Comment: I converted it into code snippet now try it @ismsm

Answer (score 0):

For working with JSON as a JS you will have to use JSON.parse().
This will spread your JSON object to an Array instance with its attribute .
Then you can loop over the array and do whatever you like.
When you are done with the instance and you want to pass it to a function , use JSON.stringify() to convert the Object to a string (which you can write or pass)